# Google Cloud Endpoints call one endpoint from another

Tags: java, static, google-cloud-endpoints

Let's say I have the following Google Cloud Endpoints:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "account.insert")
public Account insertAccount(Account account, @Named("userId") Long userId)

@ApiMethod(name = "user.get")
public User getUser(@Named("id") Long id)
```

Let's assume Account has a reference to User, which shall be created when the account is inserted. So what I need to do is look up the user by userId first to make sure it exists, then set the reference in Account.

To avoid redundancy, I decided it would be good to call getUser(userId) as this functionality exists as another endpoint.

This would work fine as long as both methods/endpoints are in the same class/file. As soon as I cross the class boundaries, I receive the following message:

"non-static method (...) cannot be referenced from a static content"

First of all, I don't understand why the content is static if it isn't marked as static in the method signature, but maybe the @ApiMethod annotation does its job here, because it is understandable that the API is exposed as a static method.

Second, I would probably be able to get around this by using a delegate function, but then I would like to know if it is considered good practice to call into one of my own endpoints from another endpoint.

Let me know what you think, please.

Comment: As it seems, my (demo) code is missing the "static" modifier and it should read "public **static** Account insertAccount(...)" and "public **static** User getUser(...)". This allows the compiler to see it as static and lets me use it from other static code. The second question remains, though: Is it a good practice to use my own api? Avoids redundancy, but may have negative side-effects which I don't see now. Any opinions?